# Sort a list dictionaries by a value of dictionary? TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key, key-value

I wrote a Python script that allows me to retrieve in a file some information like the e-value, number of accession... I then store this information in a dictionary.

```
import operator

file = open("4.A.1.1.3.txt", "r")

line = file.readline()

dico_hit = dict()

for line in file :
    if '#' not in line :

        columns = line.split()
        
        query = columns[3]
        
        accession = columns[4]
        
        evalue = columns[6]
        
        hmmfrom = int(columns[15])
        
        hmmto = int(columns[16])
        
        dico_hit[query] = {'Accession' : accession, 'E-value' : evalue,'Hmmfrom' : hmmfrom, 'Hmmto' : hmmto}
```

Here's a preview of my dictionary:

```
PTS_EIIB         {'Accession': 'PF00367.21', 'E-value': '4.9e-21', 'Hmmfrom': '2', 'Hmmto': '34'}
PTS_EIIC         {'Accession': 'PF02378.19', 'E-value': '8.9e-92', 'Hmmfrom': '1', 'Hmmto': '324'}
```

I want to sort my dictionary list by one of the dictionary values (E-value). For this I use the function "sorted".

```
sort_evalue= sorted(dico_hit, key=lambda k: k['E-value'])
print(sort_evalue)
```

I get that mistake:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I don't understand what's causing this mistake? Is this just not the right way to go about it?

Comment: You don't have a list of dictionaries, but are trying to sort a dictionary. When you're iterating, it iterates the keys of the dictionary, which are strings. You're trying to index these strings with `'E-value'`.

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be sorted. If you want a sorted list of key/value pairs this way, you can use `sorted(dico_hit.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['E-value'])`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wanted to have a sorted list of keys and values. Your method works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`dico_hit` is not a list, it is a `dict`, if you want to sort them you should use list. so before your loop:

```
dico_hit = list()
```

then append to list like this insted of `dico_hit[query] = {'Ac...`:

```
dico_hit.append({'Accession' : accession, 'E-value' : evalue,'Hmmfrom' : hmmfrom, 'Hmmto' : hmmto})
```

then your `sorted` function will work just fine.

by the way:

> you can not sort dictionary because of their base implementation. for ordering dicts you can use `collections.OrderedDict`.